# List list1 = [ 1.1, 2.1.3, 2.1 ] need out put List list2 = [ 1.1.0, 2.1.3, 2.1.0 ]

Tags: groovy

How to add .0 to in list which are less than two . (dots) or less than 3 tokens

List List1 = [  1.1, 2.1.3, 2.1 ]
need output
List list2 = [ 1.1.0, 2.1.3, 2.1.0 ]

Comment: What have you tried and how is it failing ?

Comment: I dont know how to procedd

Comment: need solutions for this.

Comment: could you please help me on this

Comment: While I think we can help you on this, note that good questions usually show what you've done and what's not working.  The question above leaves a fair amount to interpretation, and any answer provided may be wrong if someone understands your question differently than you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.count()` like this:

```
list1?.collect{it.count(".") < 2 ? "${it}.0": it}
```

To explain in case you're not familiar with this:

- collect performs the closure on each element of the list
- "it" is the item that is being acted on
- if "it" has fewer than two periods in it, return "it" + .0; otherwise just return the item